# Angular - window.screen.height doesn't work on template

Tags: css, angular, typescript, templates

I have a problem when I want to optimize part of my template for mobiles in horizontal mode.

TS:

```
window = window;
```

Template:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'height': window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth ?
 window.screen.height : (widget == 'playlist' ? '334px' : '275px')}">
</div>
```

I'm getting nothing from window.screen.height but when I log it, it's returning good values. I was trying to use it like value but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not telling your style `height` what size unit it should get. Pixels `px`, Percentage `%`, etc. I added the pixel unit as an example this:

```html
 <div [ngStyle]="{'height': window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth ?
    window.screen.height + 'px' : (widget == 'playlist' ? '334px' : '275px')}">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally miss that I forgot the set size unit.